# Tooltips in Altair line charts

Tags: python, altair

When specifying a tooltip for a line chart, the tooltip only appears when hovering over points along a line, but not when hovering anywhere else along a line. This is especially problematic when using a non-linear interpolation... Is there way to explicitly set tooltips on the lines themselves?

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.jobs.url

alt.Chart(source).mark_line(interpolate="basis").encode(
    alt.X('year:O'),
    alt.Y('perc:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='%')),
    color='sex:N',
    tooltip='sex:N'
).properties(
    title='Percent of work-force working as Welders'
).transform_filter(
    alt.datum.job == 'Welder'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Extending from @Philipp_Kats's answer and  @dominik's comment (and for anyone else who stumbled upon this thread and wish to see the Altair code example), the current way of achieving a "tooltip" effect along the lines is to:

1. Create the line (`mark_line()`)
2. Create a selection that chooses the nearest point & selects based on x-value
3. Snap some transparent selectors across the line, informing the x-value across different positions of the line
4. Layer (`mark_text()`) on top of 1 - 3 above

A real example is this [line chart on a simple Flask app I made](http://pedagogy.azurewebsites.net). Only difference was that I didn't make the selectors transparent (`opacity=alt.value(0)`) but otherwise it's a line chart with tooltips snapped on it.

Here's a reproducible example using OP's original dataset:

```
# Step 1: create the line
line = alt.Chart().mark_line(interpolate="basis").encode(
    x=alt.X("year:O"),
    y=alt.Y("perc:Q", axis=alt.Axis(format='%')),
    color='sex:N'
).transform_filter(
    alt.datum.job == 'Welder'
)

# Step 2: Selection that chooses nearest point based on value on x-axis
nearest = alt.selection(type='single', nearest=True, on='mouseover',
                            fields=['year'])


# Step 3: Transparent selectors across the chart. This is what tells us
# the x-value of the cursor
selectors = alt.Chart().mark_point().encode(
    x="year:O",
    opacity=alt.value(0),
).add_selection(
    nearest
)

# Step 4: Add text, show values in Sex column when it's the nearest point to 
# mouseover, else show blank
text = line.mark_text(align='left', dx=3, dy=-3).encode(
    text=alt.condition(nearest, 'sex:N', alt.value(' '))
)

# Layer them all together
chart = alt.layer(line, selectors, text, data=source, width=300)

chart
```

Resulting plot:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As of March 2022, a workaround for this without complicating your spec too much with selectors and Voronoi tesselation: Use a thick transparent line in the background (`opacity` should not be exactly `0`, because then it is not rendered) and create a `layer chart`.

```
base = (
    alt.Chart(
        pd.DataFrame(
            [{"x": 1, "y": 1}, {"x": 2, "y": 2}, {"x": 3, "y": 1}, {"x": 4, "y": 4}]
        )
    )
    .mark_line()
    .encode(x="x:Q", y="y:Q", tooltip="tt:N")
    .transform_calculate(tt="datum.x+' value'")
)
tt = base.mark_line(strokeWidth=30, opacity=0.01)
base + tt
```

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that there is a direct technical solution at the moment :-(

One workaround solution is to explicitly add points on top of lines so it is easier to hover. I usually make them relatively large, but hide until the hover event, like [here](https://streeteasy.com/blog/data-dashboard/) As a cherry on the top, one could use Voronoi to show the closest point at any given point, as they do in this [tutorial](https://vega.github.io/vega/tutorials/airports/)

Let me know if you need Altair code example, I used raw vega, but implementing Altair version should be relatively trivial

Comment: Vega-Lite author here: yes, this is the preferred approach right now. Tooltips at interpolated positions are problematic because tooltips usually imply some kind of precision but interpolated values are just guesses. So in a way, this is by design. In future versions, we might snap tooltips to the closest defined value.

Comment: So it looks like tooltips are always associated with points, and there is no concept of tooltips for series (i.e. "colors")?

Comment: What do you mean by that?